# Scope in JavaScript example with conflicting examples

Tags: javascript

```js
var age = 23;

function foo() {
  console.log(age);
  var age = 65;
  console.log(age);
}

foo();
```

Outputs:

```
undefined
65
```

but

```js
var a = 'hello!';
first();

function first() {
  var b = 'hi!';
  second();

  function second() {
    var c = 'hey!';
    console.log(a + b + c);
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
hello!hi!hey!
```

Why is it that in the first function, `age` is undefined, but in the second, `a` is bound correctly to `hello!`?

Comment: hen you use var in a new scope it creates a brand new variable. if you want to redefine the existing variable you need to leave the `var` off it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you use var, and write this:

```js
function foo() {
   console.log(age);
   var age = 65;
   console.log(age);
}
```

js thinks you wrote this:

```
function foo() {
   var age; // it is undefined
   console.log(age);
   age = 65;
   console.log(age);
}
```

When you declare variables with `var` the declaration of the local variable actually happens at the top of the function, and it shadows the variable from the global scope.

Also as mentioned by the comment, you should really use `let` or `const` and forget about `var`. `var` is obsolete at this point, imo.

Comment: Correct, also useful to point out that this behavior can be avoided by using **let** instead of **var** for function variables

Comment: It behaves differently because of scope, the second function is nested inside first so it will have access to variable **b** when it is console logged

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript variables are 'hoisted' that is, even that you placed `age` on the second line in `foo`, in reality the code looks like:

```
function foo() {
  var age; // which in practice means that age = undefined
  console.log(age);
  age = 65;
  console.log(age);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is because of hoisting - the wide known issue with variables created with **var** keyword. Every time you declare that way your variable bubble up to the start of the function no matter where you declare it exactly. That's why

```
function foo() {
   console.log(age);
   var age = 65;
   console.log(age);
}
```

is similar to

```
var age = 23;
function foo() {
   var age // age hoisted to here
   console.log(age);
   age = 65;
   console.log(age);
}
```

This also makes problems with loops and async operations like below:

```
function foo() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    setTimeout(()=>console.log(i), 0)
  }
}
foo()
```

Instead of expected output like 0,1,2.. you will get seven of 7 and the reason is the same - var declaration hoisting to the top of the function, it breaks down a loop scope. Then loop ends its work, **i** becomes 7 and this value gets into the setTimeout callback thanks to closure.
To avoid this, not use var at all - since the ES6 both **const** and **let** are the best practice.